# How to use the map function with conditional logic

Tags: reactjs

In the following code, components is an array of objects containing these values: `{name: '', url: '', type: '', show: 1}`

```
1 render() {
2   return (
3                   ...
4                   {this.state.editableRowData.components.map((c, i) => (
5                       <>
6                   ...
7   );
8 }
```

How do I conditionally map components to UI inside of the map function based on if the show value is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter them before mapping through the list.

```js
this.state.editableRowData.components.filter(item => item.show === 1).map((c, i) => (...rendering logic))
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you do not need map, because map creates an array of exact same size of the original array, what you need is [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which behaves almost the same as map but it filters what you do not want to be on the array, therefore you could have something like:

```
this.state.editableRowData.components.filter((c, i) => (c.show === 1));
```

working code with difference between `map` and `filter`

```js
const array = [{
    "name": 0,
    "url": 0,
    "type": 0,
    "show": 1
  },
  {
    "name": 1,
    "url": 1,
    "type": 1,
    "show": 0
  },
  {
    "name": 2,
    "url": 2,
    "type": 2,
    "show": 1
  },
  {
    "name": 3,
    "url": 3,
    "type": 3,
    "show": 0
  },
  {
    "name": 4,
    "url": 4,
    "type": 4,
    "show": 1
  }
]


const result = array.filter((item) => item.show === 1);
const resultMap = array.map((item) => (item.show === 1? item: null));

console.log(result)
console.log("------------------")
console.log(resultMap);
```